# How can I change a TextView from a custom view

Tags: android, textview

Ok, I've decided to omit any code simply because I think most will understand what I'm trying to do.

Basically I have Layout, a TextView and a custom view called GameGraphics which have all been added programmatically in the onCreate of my Activity. The GameGraphics View is a custom view where all the interaction and drawing (basic game) takes place. The TextView displays information such as the score or currentPlayer turn etc etc.

The entire interaction of the game occurs from within GameGraphics' Constructor where I have added the OnTouchListener i.e.

```
    this.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
             // ALL GAME LOGIC GOES HERE    
                            }
                           return true;
     }});
```

Now, I could just have the custom view use up the entire screen and draw the textual feedback onto the canvas, however, for the purposes of learning I would like to use the TextView. So I'm trying how to figure out how to change the TextView text as the game progresses, that is, from within GameGraphics custom View. So ultimately I'm trying to get the TextView to "listen" to the custom GameGraphics view and redraw itself with the variables such as score, currentPlayer etc.

I do understand that how I'm trying to go about it isn't going to work... I'm guessing you can't get a View to ask a different View to redraw itself while that View is still drawing... or something like that.

I'm really out of ideas. I'm assuming I might figure out what to do if someone could tell me something along the lines of having a Button, and when that button is pressed, a TextView's text changes to something else. This is ultimately what I'm trying to do I guess?

I will keep looking in the meantime...

Comment: You could just get a reference to the `TextView` and give it to the `GameGraphics` `View` when you initialize it(If I understand what you're trying to do). Then you could use that reference to do what you want. The `Lunar Lander` sample has something like this http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/LunarLander/src/com/example/android/lunarlander/index.html.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible for you to do your game logic in your main Activity, not in the GameGraphics class? That way you have a handle on the TextView object you've created, and can use .setText("your string") on the TextView any time. Hope this helps, please let me know if I've misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

This solution comes down to using the Java language elements. What we do is create an abstract listener class as a member of the same class that controls the game view. Then in the activity  create an instance of that class and implement the abstract methods you create.

```
class gameGraphics
{
   public abstract class DataListener
   {
      public abstract void updateScore(String data);
   }
   private DataListener listener;
   public gameGraphics(DataListener listener){
      this.listener = listener;
   }
   private TheMethodThatGetsCalledWhenThingsChange(){
       this.listener.updateScore(...DATA....);
   }
}

class mainActivity extends Activity
{
   @Override
   public onCreate(...stuff...){
       ...on create stuff...
       new gameGraphics(new DataListener{
           public void updateScore(String data){
              ...set the listview...
           }
       }); 
   }
}
```